# Javascript : RegExp pattern not picking up as valid Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check whether the number the user provided on the frontend matches my RegExp, as seen in the code below:

```
var patt = new RegExp("^((?:\+27|27)|0)(\d{9})\$");

if(!patt.test($('#phoneNumber').val())){
  this.error = "Please enter a valid number.";
  return;
}
```

However, I get this error in my console:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^((?:+27|27)|0)(d{9})$/:Nothing to repeat
```

I tried multiple escape approaches, but was unsuccessful.

Can someone please assist, or just show me the ropes on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a regexp from string you should use `\\` instead of every `\` (since when you create a string a single backslash is an escape character, and double backslash is a simple backslash)

Likewise if you try: `console.log('\')` vs `console.log('\\')`, for the first one you'll get the following error: `Invalid or unexpected token`

This is the full code:

```
var patt = new RegExp('^((?:\\+27|27)|0)(\\d{9})$');

if(!patt.test($('#phoneNumber').val())){
  this.error = "Please enter a valid number.";
  return;
}
```

You can achieve the same result with the following way (please note this time you don't create a string and then a regexp from the string, rather you create a regexp directly, so you don't need an escape backslash before every backslash):

```
var patt = /^((?:\+27|27)|0)(\d{9})$/
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so promptly, but that did not work for me. However, this worked for me:

`var patt = new RegExp("^(([0-9]|\\+)(\\d{9})|(\\d{11}))$");`

This is for all South African phone numbers, for anyone in the future.

Comment: Your updated answer now works for me. Thanks a mill!

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome! In the future if you want to test regex use this site: http://regexr.com/3fsdf, and remember to escape every backslash with a backslash if you create a regexp in JS from string.